# android how can i make service sleeps for 20 seconds while gitting data from location class?

Tags: android, service

i have  to get my location inside service from another class by this code

```
      Mylocation mylol = new Mylocation();
    private void locationClick() {




         mylol.getLocation(this, locationResult);


                            mylol.cancelTimer();

         // runDialog(3);

    }

    public LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
    ;
        @Override
        public void gotLocation(final Location location){
            //Got the location!
            double MyFinalLat=location.getLatitude();
            double MyFinalLon=location.getLongitude();
            Myloc=MyFinalLat+","+MyFinalLon;
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Your current location"+Myloc,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            };
        };

}
```

but i should make the gpss take his time to find locattion
how can i make my service slaaps for 20 secons for exampl??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code:

```
Thread.sleep(20000);
```

Will make the current thread sleep for 20 seconds. From an Activity, this would probably cause a force close, because it effectively make your process seem like it's locked up (I assume). In a Service, as you describe, you may be alright though.

BTW the 20 seconds isn't incredibly precise, as noted in the docs.

Comment: thank you for your help but
actually it's just like what you said it makes force close after 20 seconds
any another way the handler didn't work with me

how can i get location.getLatitude();
from this code

Answer (score 2):

```
 Handler handler = new Handler(); 
   handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
     public void run() { 
          my_button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.defaultcard); 
     } 
   }, 2000);
```